# What would I use to graph this?

Tags: statistics

If I had the following data points:

```
X | Y
1 | 12.4
9 | 13.0
11 | 16.0
```

What would I use? Linear, quadratic, or exponential regression? My guess would be to use exponential, as the points on a graph look like this:

[image]

But, the context of the problem states that the data represents population growth. So, what would I use? Linear, quadratic, or exponential regression?

Thanks so much,

Ruchi

Comment: Population is often modeled as exponential growth.

Comment: @MPW Okay, so when I do the exponential growth, I get the equation: y=7.4927 (1.0695)^2. What is the slope in that? As the question also asks what the slope is of the equation...

Comment: I don't understand that. There is no variable in your answer, only constants. If you're using an exponential model, I would assume it is of the form $y=Ae^{kx}$ and the regression produces values for $A$ and $k$. Recall also that the slope is the value of the derivative, so if $y=Ae^{kx}$ then the derivative is $y' = kAe^{kx}$. Of course, the slope depends on the value of $x$ at which you are evaluating it because the steepness varies as you move along the curve.

Comment: Tl; dr for the comment above, you're going to need an exponential function, and the slope differs at every point

Answer (score 1):

Comments:

It would be interesting to know the context of this exercise.
It is difficult to take seriously any kind of regression with only three points. Perhaps the context should determine your approach to
such a 'drill' problem.

The three points should determine a parabola, giving a
perfect fit (residuals 0). Not sure that would be considered any kind of
regression.

Below is a simple linear regression of $\log_{10}y$ on $x$ (and plotted on
a log scale for $y$) from Minitab's 'fitted line' procedure. Bands for 95% 'prediction intervals' at each point are included. 
As I understand the terminology, this is not the same thing as
log-regression. This is not a recommendation, but an attempt to
make a useful comment on possibilities opened up by the vague question.

[image]